# Does Bcrypt require anything to make it secure

Tags: php, security, encryption, bcrypt

I've been looking at encryption methods for a while now and what I've found so far is that Bcrypt is one of the best ways to do so right now. What I don't get yet is the way that Bcrypt works precisely. I understand that it takes longer to solve which is why it makes bruteforcing so hard.

But I don't understand whether it requires other measures such as a random salt to make it secure. Especially after reading about md5 and how having a random salt is almost mandatory before a hash becomes secure.

The sample code I found on php.com is this:

```
$options = [  'cost' => 12, ];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

I'm guessing the cost simply makes it so it runs through the function 12 times to encrypt the word "rasmuslerdorf". And the "PASSWORD_BCRYPT" selects the Blowfish algorithm.

Are there any big differences between PASSWORD_DEFAULT and PASSWORD_BCRYPT?
Is it enough for me to use the default function to encrypt the password on registration. And than compare the password after encrypting it that the user enters on login to the encrypted password in the database?

Comment: BCrypt is **not encryption**.

Comment: A random salt is generated each time you run `password_hash()` (unless you fix it using the options parameter).

Comment: No. But know that it truncates after 71 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm guessing the cost simply makes it so it runs through the function 12 times to encrypt the word "rasmuslerdorf"

No, the cost parameter effects an exponential amount of work to be done.

> But I don't understand whether it requires other measures such as a random salt to make it secure.

The `password_hash()` function automatically generates a random salt whenever you run it; alternatively, a custom salt can be passed via the options:

```
password_hash('bla', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['salt' => ...]);
```

By passing a custom salt you're assumed to know what you're doing. For all practical purposes you should be safe to stick with automatically generated salts.

> Are there any big differences between PASSWORD_DEFAULT and PASSWORD_BCRYPT?

The `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` algorithm is provided to future-proof your code by always using the strongest algorithm available at that time (provided you update PHP). The notable difference is in storage requirements; whereas Bcrypt always uses 60 characters, you need to cater for bigger storage (e.g. 255 characters) for whatever will be used in the future.

> And than compare the password after encrypting it that the user enters on login to the encrypted password in the database?

Please look at [`password_verify()`](http://And%20than%20compare%20the%20password%20after%20encrypting%20it%20that%20the%20user%20enters%20on%20login%20to%20the%20encrypted%20password%20in%20the%20database?) for examples on how to verify the password a user enters.

Answer (score 2):

The Bcrypt algorithm is the default algorithm. So, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` and `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` are the same. The default algorithm can be configured in your `php.ini` file, but if you did not know that then it is most likely still the default.

The `cost` number is not how many times it is hashed. How many times it is hashed is calculated by using the formula, `2^cost`. So, if the cost is 12 then it will be hashed `2^12` times (`4096`).

You do not have to think about salts when using the function. It creates the salt itself and appends it to the output hash:

```
$[algorithm]$[cost]$[salt 22 chars][rest is the hash]
```

You should never touch the hash, when using the password hashing functions. To verify a password against the has you should use `password_verify()`.

The function you are using was made so that people can hash passwords without knowing what is happening in the background. That is a good thing, because when it comes to hashing passwords it is very easy to get it wrong, even if you think you know what you are doing.